# How to rename list of Excel sheets with a list of names

Tags: list, excel, rename, spreadsheet, vba

I need to create profiles for a large list of clients. Each client has an ID number and I need to create a sheet in a workbook for each client, with the ID number for each client as the name for their respective sheets. I also have a sheet template that I would rather use to help create profiles in a uniform and professional manner. My question is: is there a way I can create a copy of the template for each of my clients and rename them with each of the ID's on my list, all at once?

Comment: Have you tried anything? `Sheets("Sheet1").Name` property? Do you have any code?

Answer (score 1):

The following VBA commands should cover what you want to do:

*Rename a sheet*

```
Sheets("Sheet5").Name = "Myname"
```

*Add a sheet, then rename it*

```
Sheets.Add
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = "MyNewSheet"
```

Comment: If you are going to use the ActiveSheet object, what is the point in going from the sheet object to its name property and then back to the sheet object? Why not just `ActiveSheet.Name = "MyNewSheet";`? My other concern is relying on that ActiveSheet to be what you think it is. I don't trust that. I would rather store a worksheet object or perform the add/rename in a single line.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff - I am sure there are many alternatives.  Your points are good ones.

Comment: i figured it out with the use of 2 macros:

Comment: macro 1: outputs a list of all sheet names in a workbook----

`Sub Sheetlist()
Dim x As Integer

Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Sheet List"
Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "New List"
For x = 1 To Worksheets.Count
Cells(x + 1, 1).Value = Worksheets(x).Name
Next x
ActiveSheet.Name = "sheetlist"
End Sub'

Comment: macro 2: replaces sheet names with a list provided in column C----

'Sub batchrename()
'
' batchrename Macro
'
Dim OldSheetName As String
Dim NewSheetName As String
Dim SheetCount As Integer
Dim NewSheetListCount As Integer

NewSheetList = InputBox("How many names are there?") + 1
For SheetCount = 1 To Range(Range("A1:A" & NewSheetListCount).Count
OldSheetName = Sheets("sheetlist").Cells(SheetCount + 1, 1)
NewSheetName = Sheets("sheetlist").Cells(SheetCount + 1, 3)

Sheets(OldSheetName).Select
ActiveSheet.Name = NewSheetName
Next SheetCount

End Sub'